# javafx 2d игры хитбоксы. пересечения

Tags: javafx, разработка-игр, 2d

есть хитбоксы в виде Rectangle. они могут вращаться и перемещаться.

как искать "столкновения" этих ректанглов?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в javafx есть такая функция intersects.
Вот пример :

```
//Создаем хит-боксы
Rectangle playerHitBox = new Rectangle(...);
Rectangle enemyHitBox = new Rectangle(...);

//Проверяем на столкновение
if (playerHitBox.intersects(enemyHitBox)) {
    //Дальше реагирование на это столкновение
}
```

Comment: да, верно.. можно. вопрос старый, проблема решена.

Comment: решена путем: 

1) проверяем на пересечение ректанглов. если оно есть -> 2 
2) проверяем пересечение с хитбоксом (набор прямых)

1 действие обезопасит от кучи лишних проверок. но не даст 100% точности из-за изменений размера ректангла при повороте.